# Mysql Database - Average value

Tags: mysql, sql, average

Here's a question:

Using appropriate column names, show admit id and average obs value for obs type 'CONT' where the average obs value of the CONT is >= 40.
Lets say admit is table1 and observe is table2 but with the same primary key Admit_id. I'm trying to get the result where average of obs value is greater than 40 but 
however I got this error instead: Unknown column 'Average' in 'where clause. Any solution here?

```
Select
    ADMIT.Admit_id,
    (SELECT AVG(Obs_value) FROM OBSERVE) AS Average
from
    ADMIT,OBSERVE
Where
    ADMIT.Admit_id=OBSERVE.Admit_id
AND
    OBSERVE.Obs_type = 'CONT'
AND
    Average >=40;
```

Comment: If you are learning SQL, you should learn explicit `join` syntax and the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

you should try joining the two tables 
and you cant reference an alias inside the `WHERE` .. it has to be `HAVING`. so something like this..

```
SELECT a.Admit_id, AVG(o.Obs_value) AS Average
FROM ADMIT a
JOIN OBSERVE o ON o.admit_id = a.admit_id
WHERE o.Obs_type = "CONT"
GROUP BY a.Admit_id
HAVING Average >=40;
```

Think of it this way...
 
`SELECT` is making an order at a restaurant....
`FROM` and `JOIN` is saying what menu's you want to order from....
 
`WHERE` is any customization you want to make to your order (aka no mushrooms)....
 
`GROUP BY` and anything after is after the order has been completed and is at your table...
 
`ORDER BY` is saying what dishes you want first (aka i want my entree then dessert then appetizer ).
 
`HAVING` can be used to pick out any mushrooms that were accidentally left on the plate....
 
etc..
 I know its a weird analogy but its a good way to understand how it works..
the alias to a table cannot be referenced until you create that table with your select you could also make it a sub select and do the same thing with a WHERE like so

```
SELECT *
FROM 
( ... your_inner_select -- without the HAVING
)t -- every table must have an alias
WHERE t.Average >=40
```